# Select2 with Sharepoint API - how to?

Tags: javascript, rest, custom-form, sharepoint-rest-api, choice-field

So for the whole day I've been trying to create a select2 javascript selectbox that would display certain list elements using API. I have found a couple of articles such as [Understanding SP Rest API](http://michaelsoriano.com/understanding-sharepoint-rest-api-part-1-selecting-items/) or  [SP Jslink select2](https://kogzee.wordpress.com/2015/03/11/select2-jquery-plugin-used-in-a-sharepoint-form-jslink/) and all i was able to come up so far was:

```
    $('.js-data-example-ajax').select2({

    id: function(e) {
        return (e.id ? e.id : e.ID);
    },
    ajax:  {   url: "mydomain/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('S')/Items?$select=Title",
    type: "GET",     
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    dataType: 'json',


width: '400px',
});
```

Using some developer tools i have found that adress it is trying to access is: `/_api/search/?term=value+&_type=query&q=value+` where `value` is what was entered into the search box. This is definitely different to what was described in the first article as the correct address. Can someone please just point me in the right direction as to how should I approach this problem and make select2 work with Sharepoint's list. Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you directly paste this in browser window `mydomain/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('S')/Items?$select=Title` and hit enter

Comment: Hey, thanks for trying to help! https://i.imgur.com/FZcSLAw.png That happens. I get the list of all elements that shows their Title.

Comment: That means your REST API is working fine, can you make it work outside SharePoint, for example in a separate HTML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i think i figured that out. The sharepoint API does not work with query parameters provided by select2. So essentialy you need to query for the whole list first and then in processResults function convert them into a format that is acceptable by select2 like so:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "text": "Option 1"
    },
}
```

I completely changed the way I am doing it and unfortunately cannot find a function I used to make it work now, but it is a simple one that just goes through all displayed elements by the API request and pushes them into the object that can be used as data source for select2.

EDIT:
If i remember correctly function was like so:

```
 processResults: function (data) {
          new_data = [];
        data.items.forEach(function(i, item) {
          new_data.push({
            id: i.name,
            text: i.name
          }); });
return {
          results: new_data
        };
}
```